# returning specific version of DTO based on user role

Tags: java, dto

I have a JobDTO class

```
class JobDTO{
 private Integer id;
 private String jobTitle;
 private String secreateData;
...
}
```

I have a BidDTO class

```
class BidDTO{
  private Integer id;
  private String bidDetails;
  private JobDTO jobDTO;

  public BidDTO(Integer id, String bidDetails, JobDTO jobDTO){
   this.id = id;
   this.bidDetails = bidDetails;
   this.jobDTO = jobDTO;
    }
 }
```

The reason I have `JobDTO` in `BidDTO` is because when I return a bid I need to return the related job details as well. The question is that what I want to hide the `secretData` in `JobDTO` from user based on users's role?

One solution could be to put individual `JobDTO` fields in `BidDTO` that I want to show to user rather than having a `JobDTO` object as part of it but what if there are 100 fields in `JobDTO` and I only have one `secretData` field that want to hide.

Comment: set secretData value is null?

Comment: yep, and is that "acceptable" to make one dto part of another dto?

Comment: @ToseefZafar May I know how you solved it?

Comment: I cant remember but  I think setting that field to null would remove that field from the response.